# How to iterate through this three dimensional array

Tags: arrays, algorithm, data-structures

Assuming I have three arrays:

```
array1 = [1,2,3,4];
array2 = [5,6,7];
array3 = [8,9,10,11];
```

and would like to get an output like this:

```
1,5,8,2,6,9,3,7,10,4,11
```

Therefore outputting the items in the array vertically.

```
|---------------------|
|     1   2   3   4   |
|     5   6   7       |
|     8   9  10  11   |
|---------------------|
```

What is the most efficient way to get the output?

Comment: There is no three-dimensional array. Not even something similar to it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
<?php
$array1 = [1,2,3,4];
$array2 = [5,6,7];
$array3 = [8,9,10,11];

    $a = count($array1);
    $b = count($array2);
    $c = count($array3); 
    $highest_number = max($a, $b, $c);
    $fvar = "";
    for ($x = 0; $x <= $highest_number; $x++) {
     if(!empty($array1[$x])){
         $fvar.=",".$array1[$x];
     }
          if(!empty($array2[$x])){
         $fvar.=",".$array2[$x];
     }

                  if(!empty($array3[$x])){
         $fvar.=",".$array3[$x];
     }
    } 
    $fvar  = ltrim($fvar,",");
    echo  $fvar ; 

?>
```

result = 1,5,8,2,6,9,3,7,10,4,11
//update to make it as array you can

```
$farray = explode(",",$fvar);
```

example :
http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/5606877200b52828e94bbc43d31e9f335bf7a294

Answer (score -2):

```
int i=0,n1= array1.length,n2=array2.length,n3=array3.length;

while(i<n1||i<n2||i<n3) {
  if(i<n1) print(array1[i]);
  if(i<n2) print(array2[i]);
  if(i<n3) print(array3[i]);
  i++;
}
```

Comment: Please look at [answer]